# Convert hex representation inside a string to binary equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, string

In a string, replace every occurrence of <0xYZ> with the character of hex value YZ. The < and > characters will be used only for that purpose, the string is guaranteed to be well formatted.

Example ('0' = 0x30): `A<0x30>B` => `A0B`

It's an easy task, but there are many solutions and I was wondering about the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a regular expression replace is the easiest way:

```
s = Regex.Replace(
  s,
  @"<0[Xx]([\dA-Fa-f]{2})>",
  m => ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString()
);
```

By matching an exact pattern it places less restrictions on the string, for example that the `<` and `>` characters can still be used. Also, if a tag would happen to be malfomed, it will simply be left unchaged instead of causing an exception.

This will replace tags like `<0X4A>` and `<0x4a>`, but leave for example `<0x04a>` unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with a regular expression:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "<0x([0-9a-f]+)>",
      m => Char.ConvertFromUtf32(
                      Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.HexNumber))
      );
```

It is probably missing a few error checks. This uses an [overload of `Regex.Replace` that takes a `MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Match the number and convert to int then to char.

```
var str = "A<0x30>B";

var result = Regex.Replace(str, "<0x((\\d|[A-Z])+)>",
    delegate (Match m)
    {
        return ((char)Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value, 16)).ToString();
    }, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Output

```
A0B
```